# Travel planning app — best navigation pattern for horizontal scrolling?

Tags: usability, navigation, web-app, scrolling

I'm designing a trip planning app that allows users to create events under vertical 'Day Columns.' It scrolls horizontally.

However, the 'Day' columns containing events are potentially infinite and it's important for the user to be able to navigate back and forth between weeks (Week 1, Week 2, Week 3).

I'm wondering what you think the best practice is for this problem, and if there are any designs out there that solve a similar problem? Any input would be much appreciated.

You can see my attempt in the wireframe below, but it feels a little awkward. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Do you want to display all of the information of the event upfront in the card? You can just show the title of the event upfront with some important date and make the card expandable in order to view more information. This way you would be able to save space.

Answer (score 1):

What you want here is to implement a system of data presentation that every user came across at least once in their life - calendar. Your calendar can highlight days that contain events. The list of events per day will be limited, so the scroll navigation will be appropriate.

Great UX examples:

[image]   [image]